# Can you compare varchar field one of table and char field of another table

Tags: sql, database

Can you compare varchar field one of table  and char field of another table ?

Comment: Nope, it's forbidden by law and you might get prosecuted if you try it at your home. Be careful!

Comment: Specific details might help your cause. Right now you have a vague question that may be answered with "sure" but I doubt that would help you much less anyone else either. What is your use case? Are the tables on the same DB? When you say compare, what do you mean? Check for equality what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728815/left-outer-join-getting-me-nulls-on-right-table-when-there-are-records/44729578#44729578

Comment: Please take a look at my question, I have left outer join on varchar field = char field. I am getting (null)values from the right table when there are actually records in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can it.

first table have;

```
VARCHAR_COLUMN varchar(10)
```

second table have;

```
CHAR_COLUMN char(10)
```

you can use;

```
CHAR_COLUMN = VARCHAR_COLUMN
```

or convert;

```
Convert(varchar(10), CHAR_COLUMN) = VARCHAR_COLUMN
```